# mod_fcgid read data timeout - Premature end of script headers

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, fastcgi, plesk

The websites on one of my Plesk users can't be accessed. The server reports a 500 Internal server error, the error_log for that user shows a bunch of

```
[warn] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 60 seconds
[error] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

The DocumentRoot contains a normal WordPress installation. Other sites running the same WP version, using the same DB server and PHP+Extensions run fine. A `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` runs fine as well. Calling `php index.php` from cli returns the webpage, but is a bit too slow for an **idle Xeon E5-2620 Server w/ 64GB RAM**

Are there any known Problems? How can I debug further?

Some more system info:

- PHP 5.6.24 (tried 5.4 as well)
- Plesk 12.5.30

EDIT: The Problem occurs intermittently. Right now, no 500 Error is returned, site loads fine (a bit slow). I increased memory_limit, just to be sure it isn't a config limitation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a rogue `file_get_contents` in some scripts.

I looked through the error log for the 1st appearance of the error message, and found a file created exactly when the error message first appeared - only 2 years earlier...
[WordPress Site hacked? Suspicious PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012433/wordpress-site-hacked-suspicious-php-file/39013819#39013819)

So I removed the malware ( detailed write-up at https://talk.plesk.com/threads/debugging-premature-end-of-script-headers.338956/ ), rebooted the Server and the error is now gone.

Technical detail: The error turned up because the Server distributing the malware is offline. `file_get_contents("http..."` timed out, the local script failed and returned the error message.

Comment: Btw, there is extensions which may be handy in such cases https://ext.plesk.com/packages/6bcc01cf-d7bb-4e6a-9db8-dd1826dcad8f-security-advisor, https://ext.plesk.com/packages/e757450e-40a5-44e5-a35d-8c4c50671019-dgri, https://ext.plesk.com/packages/24e15804-3134-4561-a2a2-1bdc7228e98f-website-virus-check

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into Linux Server Virus scanners. VirusTotal reports ESET and Fortinet are the only ones detecting the Scripts as malware. ClamAV and drwebd didn't detect them. First run of ESET seems promising...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase FcgidIOTimeout as described here https://kb.plesk.com/en/121251

`Since Plesk 11.5, "FcgidIOTimeout" parameter is set to the same value as max_execution_time php parameter in domain's PHP settings`

Also you can try any of PHP-FPM handler instead of FastCGI, because of mod_fcgid has a lot of internal performance limitations which can't be avoided.

Comment: Increasing timeout only mitigates the issue, the page (wordpress) would still load for >1min on that idle server... Currently looking into FPM compatibility with PHP versions and Plesk.

Comment: Does opcache module is enabled for current handler? You can check it with phpinfo();

Comment: Also you can check for query cache in MySQL, and maybe to find WP plug-in which slow down this WordPress instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, FPM doesn't work well with Apache 2.2, which is default in Ubuntu 12.04... I logged all queries of mysql for 15 minutes. Quite a lot, but nothing suspicious. Now looking into debugging PHP to see where it hangs...